# How to configure routeConfig.cs to take input directly after root domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routeconfig

Check the code bellow. Here in route i want to give user enter input of username in url just like `example.com/username` but problem with that `RouteConfig.cs` is this cant take input like that. This will only take `controller/method format`. Please advice me how can i achieve domain/username type input form user? I want to serve that request from `Test` method bellow

Currently RouteConfig.cs file:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Test method:

```
public ActionResult Test(String username)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
routes.MapRoute("Id"
              , "{id}"
                , new { controller = "Home", action = "Test"});
```

Comment: yes this hits the Test method but no value in string. i tried domain/username value

Comment: Try changing {id} to {username}